# How do I add a library project to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, dependency-management, android-library

How do I add a library project (such as Sherlock ABS) to [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio)?

(Not to the old ADT Eclipse-based bundle, but to the new [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio).)

Comment: yeah figuring this out was way more confusing than it should have been... not like it was any better in eclipse.

Comment: The YouTube video *[How to Add Libraries to Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk)* explains the process.

Answer (score 731, accepted):

**Update for Android Studio 1.0**

Since Android Studio 1.0 was released (and a lot of versions between v1.0 and one of the firsts from the time of my previous answer) some things has changed.

My description is focused on adding external library project by hand via Gradle files (for better understanding the process). If you want to add a library via Android Studio creator just check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16634680/2021293) below with visual guide (there are some differences between Android Studio 1.0 and those from screenshots, but the process is very similar).

Before you start adding a library to your project by hand, consider adding the external dependency. It won’t mess in your project structure. Almost every well-known Android library is available in a [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) repository and its installation takes only one line of code in the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
}
```

**Adding the library**

Here is the full process of adding external Android library to our project:

1. Create a new project via Android Studio creator. I named it *HelloWorld*.
2. Here is the original project structure created by Android Studio:

> ```
> HelloWorld/
>       app/
>            - build.gradle  // local Gradle configuration (for app only)
>            ...
>       - build.gradle // Global Gradle configuration (for whole project)
>       - settings.gradle
>       - gradle.properties
>       ...
> ```

3. In the root directory (`HelloWorld/`), create new folder: `/libs` in which we’ll place our external libraries (this step is not required - only for keeping a cleaner project structure).
4. Paste your library in the newly created `/libs` folder. In this example I used [PagerSlidingTabStrip library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) (just download ZIP from GitHub, rename library directory to „PagerSlidingTabStrip" and copy it). Here is the new structure of our project:

> ```
> HelloWorld/
>       app/
>            - build.gradle  // Local Gradle configuration (for app only)
>            ...
>       libs/
>            PagerSlidingTabStrip/
>                 - build.gradle // Local Gradle configuration (for library only)
>       - build.gradle // Global Gradle configuration (for whole project)
>       - settings.gradle
>       - gradle.properties
>       ...
> ```

5. Edit settings.gradle by adding your library to `include`. If you use a custom path like I did, you have also to define the project directory for our library. A whole settings.gradle should look like below:

   ```
    include ':app', ':PagerSlidingTabStrip'
    project(':PagerSlidingTabStrip').projectDir = new File('libs/PagerSlidingTabStrip')
   ```

5.1 If you face "Default Configuration" error, then try this instead of step 5,

```
    include ':app'
    include ':libs:PagerSlidingTabStrip'
```

6. In `app/build.gradle` add our library project as an dependency:

   ```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        implementation project(":PagerSlidingTabStrip")
    }
   ```

6.1. If you followed step 5.1, then follow this instead of 6,

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

        implementation project(":libs:PagerSlidingTabStrip")
    }
```

7. If your library project doesn’t have `build.gradle` file you have to create it manually. Here is example of that file:

   ```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

        dependencies {
            implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
        }

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 21
            buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 21
            }

            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res']
                }
            }
        }
   ```
8. Additionally you can create a global configuration for your project which will contain SDK versions and build tools version for every module to keep consistency. Just edit `gradle.properties` file and add lines:

   ```
    ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
    ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=21
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=21.1.3
    ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=21
   ```

   Now you can use it in your `build.gradle` files (in app and libraries modules) like below:

   ```
    //...
    android {
        compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
        buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
            targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
        }
    }
    //...
   ```
9. That’s all. Just click‚ synchronise the project with the Gradle’ icon [image: synchronise with Gradle]. Your library should be available in your project.

*[Google I/O 2013 - The New Android SDK Build System](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0)*  is a great presentation about building Android apps with Gradle Build System: As Xavier Ducrohet said:

> Android Studio is all about editing, and debugging and profiling.
> It's not about building any more.

At the beginning it may be little bit confusing (especially for those, who works with [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and have never seen the ant - like me ;) ), but at the end Gradle gives us some great opportunities and it worth to learn this build system.

Comment: hey there, you perfectly explained the real issue. voting up your answer so other people can see it.

one minor thing that didn't work on my side is referencing the support library in the dependency's build.gradle. as it turns out ':Project/libs...' did not work for some reason. i had to do away with the project identification. so 'libs/...'. and it compiled fine.

one note is that these two ways of referencing paths or projects is confusing. i hope a simple and unified scheme comes up in the future. there is no reason why the original solution wouldn't work.

Comment: +1. Was struggling with this for a long time. As *victor n* said, referencing the main project's support jar from actionbarsherlock module doesn't work. I had to do the following to get it working... (1) Remove **compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')** from the project's build.gradle. The main module should only have **compile project(":libraries:actionbarsherlock")**. (2) Add **compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')** instead of **compile files(':HelloWorld/libs/android-support-v4.jar')** in actionbarsherlock's build.gradle.

Comment: In your solution, my libraries need to be inside my project structure. What if I want to use a Library Project as dependency in several projects? How do I add to my gradle an external module dependency?

Comment: @Akbaribrahim you are right. Including support library in two projects is bad practise. Here you have good answer how to add support library into two or more projects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16746682/2021293

Comment: tried and tried.. just kept on getting this error: `Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':HelloWorld'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

i also tried suggestions by @victorn. and akbar ibrahim.. still didn't work for me

Comment: I can't find the sherlock library project after i copy it to the libraries folder. when I try to import a module.

Comment: Where is `Global libraries` (#10: "now go to Global libraries")? Other than that, it works as described :) Thanks so much. (I hope Google will get down to it - such a simple task is headscratchingly complex at the moment)

Comment: Why dont i have "Import Module" section, at the option where you direct us ? I'm using Android Studio 0.3.1

Comment: Import Module option is missing!!

Comment: This answer is not up to date with the current Android Studio version.

Comment: You were right. I've just updated my answer to the newest Android Studio (1.0) version.

Comment: I tried both 5 and 5.1 and in both cases i got the error: Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found. It is not working for me :/ @froger_mcs

Comment: The library must be unzipped?

Comment: @Celly @ArulxZ Try this instead on 5/5.1 `project(':PagerSlidingTabStrip').projectDir = new File('app/libs/PagerSlidingTabStrip')` for example

Comment: My project correpted thanks :)           Error:(64, 0) No such property: sonatypeUsername for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>

Comment: @roger_mcs please replace `compile` keyword with `implementation`.

Answer (score 275):

Here is the visual guide:

**Update** for Android Studio 0.8.2:

In Android Studio 0.8.2, go to **Project Structure** -> under **Modules** just hit the plus button and select **Import Existing Project** and import `actionbarsherlock`. Then synchronise your Gradle files.

If you face the error

> Error: The SDK Build Tools revision (xx.x.x) is too low. Minimum
>   required is yy.y.y

just open the `build.gradle` file in `actionbarsherlock` directory and update the `buildToolsVersion` to the suggested one.

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion 'yy.y.y'
```

[image: Android Studio 0.8.2]

---

Menu *File* -> *Project Structure...*:

[image: First]

*Module* -> *Import Module*

[image: Second]

After importing the library module, select *your* project module and add the dependency:

[image: Third]

And then select the *imported module*:

[image: Forth]

Comment: Import module option not available in Android Studio4.3

Comment: The key for me to make this work and resolve the package not found errors was the step `Select your project module and add dependency`

`dependencies {
    // ...
    compile project(':library')
}`

Comment: This will copy the library module in your project, which is not what you want if you want a common code base shared between several projects

Comment: @amalBit are... are you from the future?  But seriously, they need to make this simple like it was in Eclipse ADT; who wants to hit a third-party repo and compile (potentially) arbitrary code into each build?  That seriously undermines QA and code-freeze protocols

Comment: It was way back during beta days of Android studio 0.4.3. As for accession 3rd party repo, id say, avoid using +. Just specify the version u want. If u still cant trust it enough, u can create a jar(or clone) of any repo and use it.

Answer (score 114):

Use menu *File* -> *Project Structure* -> *Modules*.

I started using it today. It is a bit different.

For Sherlock, maybe you want to delete their test directory, or add the `junit.jar` file to the classpath.

To import the library using gradle, you can have to add it to the `dependencies` section of your  `build.gradle` (the module's one).

E.g.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Android Studio is changing.

There exist a section named "Open module settings" if you
right-click on a module folder in the project section of Android
Studio (I'm using the version 0.2.10).

Comment: Hmm it still says android-apt-compiler: styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: Under the Sherlock Module -> Dependecies I have android 4.2.2 and the support Library v4

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK next to the run button, there is a label with Android. If you ckick there you will find Edit Configuration. Push and under Target Device click on "Show Chooser Dialg"

Comment: @Alex under MyProject I ve Android 4.2.2 and the Sherlock dependecies. How does your looks like?

Comment: Hi, I've the same problem like Alex ("Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.") - the Java dependency seems to be solved correctly, cause the IDE doesn't blame my SherlockActivity, but for some reason Gradle doesn't seem to look into the ressources of ABS. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alex and fish, see my answer below. I had the same problem as you and fixed it by adding the sherlock module as a dependency to my main app module.

Comment: @fish Check my answer, it may solve your problem. ABS may be compiled as an application project instead of a library project.

Comment: This is not advisable way as this doesn't write back changes to your build.gradle file at moment. We should edit build.gradle file directly as i mentioned in my answer below.

Comment: FYI on the first update Google pushed to AS this week, the Project UI is now gone and a message dialog is in its place telling the user to edit the gradle files directly.

Comment: Try this: Compile project. Click on error. A light bulb button hovers over the error line. Click it and select the desired action (like `"add to class-path"`) to fix the problem.

Comment: On Android Studio 0.2.8 there is no `Modules` section in the `Project Structure` window.

Comment: I find out that exist a section named "Open module settings" if you right-click on a module folder in the project section of android studio (I'm using the version 0.2.10)

Comment: I'm using version 0.5.8 and in File > Project Structure > Modules is a sub-menu, but I can't right click on it and there's nothing close to Module Settings or anything. There is a tab called Dependencies, where I suppose you set the build path. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in 0.8.2

Answer (score 53):

I would consider [Dependencies, Android Libraries and Multi-project setup](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup) necessary reading. Please take a few minutes to do so.

Particularly, in the case of a non-jar library project, read the following snippet from above source:

> Gradle projects can also depend on other gradle projects by using a multi-project setup.
>   A multi-project setup usually works by having all the projects as sub folders of a given root project.
>
> For instance, given to following structure:

```
MyProject/
 + app/
 + libraries/
    + lib1/
    + lib2/
```

> We can identify 3 projects. Gradle will reference them with the following name:

```
:app
:libraries:lib1
:libraries:lib2
```

> Each projects will have its own build.gradle declaring how it gets built.
>   Additionally, there will be a file called settings.gradle at the root declaring the projects.
>   This gives the following structure:

```
MyProject/
 | settings.gradle
 + app/
    | build.gradle
 + libraries/
    + lib1/
       | build.gradle
    + lib2/
       | build.gradle
```

> The content of settings.gradle is very simple:

```
include ':app', ':libraries:lib1', ':libraries:lib2'
```

> This defines which folder is actually a Gradle project.
>
> The :app project is likely to depend on the libraries, and this is done by declaring the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:lib1')
}
```

Kindly note that there was little or no use of Android Studio GUI to make this happen.

I am currently using [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to link the nested library to the actual library git repo to avoid a dependency mess.

Answer (score 29):

I have just found an easier way (rather than writing directly into the .gradle files).

This is for Android Studio 1.1.0.

1. Menu *File* -> *New Module...*:

   [image: Import Existing Project]

   Click on "Import Existing Project".
2. Select the desired library and the desired module.
3. Click finish.
   Android Studio will import the library into your project. It will sync gradle files.
4. Add the imported module to your project's dependencies.

   Right click on the app folder -> Open Module settings -> go to the dependencies tab -> Click on the '+' button -> click on Module Dependency.

   The library module will be then added to the project's dependencies.

   [image: Add library module]
5. ???
6. Profit

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way I found to include external library project is (for example to include a Facebook library which is stored one directory up in the dependencies folder):

1. In settings.gradle add

   ```
   include ':facebook'

   project(':facebook').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../dependencies/FacebookSDK')
   ```
2. In build.gradle dependencies section, add

   ```
   compile project ('facebook')
   ```

All left to do is synchronise the project with gradle files.

Comment: Hi Vilen what is settingsDir here

Comment: Hi Rajnish. From documentation: settingsDir  Returns the settings directory of the build. The settings directory is the directory containing the settings file.
Returns:
The settings directory. Never returns null.

Comment: The two dots before /dependencies are more important to be cared Your answer helper me a lot.. Thanks

Comment: **NOTE:** for string evaluation in gradle you must use double quote ("). This "save the day" for me. Linked to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171049/gradle-single-vs-double-quotes)

Answer (score 16):

A simple way to add a JAR file as a library to your Android Studio project:

a) Copy your *.jar files

b) Paste into the *libs* directory under your projects:

[image]

c) Add to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile files('libs/ScanAPIAndroid.jar', 'libs/ScanAPIFactoryAndroid.jar', .., ..)
}
```

b) **If your project from example com.example.MYProject and libraries com.example.ScanAPI has the same namespace com.example**, Android Studio will check your build and create all necessary changes in your project. After that you can review these settings in menu *File* -> *Project Structure*.

c) **If your project and libraries have a different namespace** you have to right click on the library and select option "Add as Library" and select the type what you need.

Remember the "Project structure" option is not doing any auto changes in "build.gradle" in the current version of Android Studio (0.2.3). Maybe this feature will be available in the next versions.

Answer (score 13):

### Option 1: Drop Files Into Project's libs/directory

The relevant build.gradle file will then update automatically.

### Option 2: Modify build.gradle File Manually

Open your build.gradle file and add a new build rule to the dependencies closure. For example, if you wanted to add Google Play Services, your project's dependencies section would look something like this:

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
   }
```

### Option 3: Use Android Studio's User Interface

In the Project panel, <kbd>Control</kbd> + click the module you want to add the dependency to and select Open Module Settings.

[image]

Select the Dependencies tab, followed by the + button in the bottom-left corner. You can choose from the following list of options:

- Library Dependency
- File Dependency
- Module Dependency

You can then enter more information about the dependency you want to add to your project. For example, if you choose Library Dependency, Android Studio displays a list of libraries for you to choose from.

Once you've added your dependency, check your module-level build.gradle file. It should have automatically updated to include the new dependency.

[Source](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-gradle--cms-22978)

Answer (score 12):

### **This is how it works for me in Android Studio 1.5+**

In the project where you want to add external library project,
go to menu *File* -> *New* -> *Import new Module**, navigate to the library project which you want to add to your project, select to add 'library' module in your project. You will get **settings.gradle** in your projects, beside app, included library, something like this:

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

Add in **build.gradle(Module :app)** in the dependencies section:

**Compile project(':library')**

Rebuild the project, and that's it.

*You can add as many libraries (modules) as you want. In that case in settings.gradle you will have:

```
 include ':app', ':lib1', ':lib2', ...
```

And in build.gradle, you'll need to have:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Some other dependencies...

    compile project(':lib1')
    compile project(':lib2')
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do this easily. Go to menu *File* -> *New* -> *Import Module...*:

[image]

Browse for the directory which contains the module. Click Finish:

[image]

Go to *Project Structure* and add *Module Dependency*:

[image]

Note: If you receive an SDK error, update that one.

Answer (score 9):

1. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to show **Project Structure**, click libraries or Global libraries, and click <kbd>+</kbd> to add the JAR file.
2. Click Modules what you want add jar, select the **Dependencies** tab, click <kbd>+</kbd>, and add Library.

Answer (score 9):

If you need access to the resources of a library project (as you do with ABS) ensure that you add the library project/module as a "Module Dependency" instead of a "Library".

Answer (score 6):

Editing library dependencies through the GUI is not advisable as that doesn't write those changes to your build.gradle file. So your project will not build from the command-line. We should edit the build.gradle file directly as follows.

For instance, given to following structure:

MyProject/

- app/
- libraries/

  - lib1/
  - lib2/

We can identify three projects. Gradle will reference them with the following names:

1. :app
2. :libraries:lib1
3. :libraries:lib2

The :app project is likely to depend on the libraries, and this is done by declaring the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:lib1')
}
```

Comment: Really? Strange, they have the whole GUI and yet it's not advisable. How so?

Comment: As editing through GUI doesn't writes those changes to your build.gradle file. GUI editing only saves changes in IntelliJ's own project data. This is a bug at the moment which will be fixed in future releases. You can refer to this answer from Google Android-Studio Team Lead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678447/android-studio-are-library-project-dependencies-picked-from-project-properties

Answer (score 6):

### Android Studio 3.0

Just add the library name to the dependencies block of your app's *build.gradle* file.

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.example:some-library:1.0.0'
}
```

Note that you should use `implementation` rather than `compile` now. This is new with Android Studio 3.0. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle) for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: It's actually a change in Gradle 4, not Android Studio 3. You can continue to use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` instead of 3.0.0 in Android Studio 3 if you want to continue using "compile".

Answer (score 5):

To add to the answer: If the IDE doesn't show any error, but when you try to compile, you get something like:

```
No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'
```

Your library project is probably compiled as an application project. To change this, go to:

Menu *File* -> *Project structure* -> *Facets* -> [Library name] -> Check "Library module".

Answer (score 5):

**First Way** This is working for MacBook.

First select your builder.gradle file as given screen:

[image]

Add dependencies like as on the selected screen:

[image]

Select sync project.

If you are getting an error like "Project with path':signature-pad' could not be found in project ':app'", then please use the second way:

Select menu *File* -> *New* -> *Import Module...*:

[image]

After clicking on *Import Module*,

[image]

give the path of library like as my MacBook path:

[image]

Click on *Finish*. Now your library are added.

Answer (score 4):

After importing the ABS Module (from File > Project Structure) and making sure it has Android 2.2 and Support Library v4 as dependencies, I was still getting the following error as you @Alex

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar'
```

I added the newly imported module as a dependency to my main app module and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I tried all steps inclusing adding the module as a dependency but I still have `Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.Light'.`. It seems like my main project does not see the resources of the library project (ABS). The IDE however does recognize the references to classes and resources. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/3yQzRbZ.png)

Comment: I'm migrate to IDEA 13 from 12 and have this error too. Only re-import for all my dependencies will help. Manually remove all modules, remove related *.iml files and re-import your libs

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this problem, you just need to add the abs resource path to your project build file, just like below:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res','../../ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock/res']
    }
}
```

So, I again compile without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Android Studio .0.4.0, you can create a new folder in your build path, `YourApp/libraries`. Copy the JAR file. There in, right click on it and "Add As Library". Now you have a popup. Just select your directory and press OK, and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1e3eteu3h0pmkf7/Android%20studio%20_doc.doc?dl=0 is the Dropbox link of how to add a JAR file and library project in the latest version of Android Studio 1.0.1.

Please see the documentation with screenshots. It's very easy for a new user.

Answer (score 3):

Simply import the Android library project as a module and in **Build.gradle**.

Apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

After that, follow these steps:

1. Right click on Module & select open Module settings
2. Select dependencies, click on <kbd>+</kbd>, select library dependencies, and add the previously imported module.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It's so simple. Follow [froger_mcs instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227).

*Make sure that you make the src folder a Source folder* in Project Structure -> Modules (Sources).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a different cause of the problem so for people:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

change mavenCentral() to jcenter() and add

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the build gradle module app file and add your dependency. If you download the library, just import and build as gradle.

Otherwise add repositories in side gradle module app:

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
}
```

The first repositories will download the library for you.

And compile the downloaded library:

```
 compile ('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

If you are creating a library, you just need to import the project as import new module.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can include your JAR files in three different ways. The last one is remote library that is using https://bintray.com/ jcenter online repository. But, if you do it in one of the two other ways, the JAR file will be included physically in your project. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941 for more information. In this post I explained how to import your JAR file in Android studio and I explained all possible ways.

In summary, if it is like this (local address), they are downloaded and these JAR files are physically in the project:

[image]

But, if it is an internet address like this, they are remote libraries (bintray.com jcenter part) and they will be used remotely:

[image]

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For Android Studio:

[image]

Click on *Build.gradle (module: app)*.

And add for

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
}
```

and in your directory "app", create a directory, "libs". Add the file yourfile.jar:

[image]

Finally, compile the Gradle Files:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, go to inside app folder, and open build.gradle file. Here you will see dependencies{}. Inside it you can add the library project and synchronise. Now after synchronising the library it will be added to your project, and you can use its functions and classes in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem then I did following things.

1. I import the library project into my AndroidStudio IDE as a module using menu *File* -> Import module  menus
2. Then I went to my main module in which I want the library project as a dependent project
3. Right click on the main module (in my case its name is **app**) -> open module setting -> go into dependencies tab -> click on + button (you will get it on right side of window) -> click on module dependency -> select your library project from list

Apply the changes and click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

It worked for me. I hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use `Gradle dependency configuration`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61185954/4770877) to add some dependency into your project

<module_name>/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  //<gradle_dependency_configuration> '<dependency_name>:<dependency_version>'
  //e.g.
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:1.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.**kts**):

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")
}
```

If you have the library file (.jar or .aar file) in your file system (e.g. have downloaded it), do this:

```kotlin
implementation(
    files(
        "$rootDir/myLibs/my-library.jar",
        "another/path/to/library-2.aar",
        // etc.
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Indeed as versions are changing, so is changing the user interface and options available on the menu. After reading most of the answers to these questions I had to guess what would work for **Android Studio 1.1.0**.

1. With your mouse, select the project at the main level (this is where it shows the name of your app).
2. Right click, and select the menu options **New, Folder, Assets Folder**.
3. After creating the assets folder, paste or copy in it, whatever JAR file you need for your library.
4. From Android Studio's main menu (top of the screen) select *File* -> *Project Structure*.
5. Then select your project name and go to the **Dependencies** tab.
6. Click on the plus sign (<kbd>+</kbd>) on the lower left of the dialog box and select file dependency.
7. Finally open the recently created assets folder, select the JAR files that you copied, and then click apply and <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: making copies of jars in assets is not a good idea it will unnecessarily increase apk size

Comment: Thanks for the advise @RajnishMishra.  I suspected that, but what do you propose instead?

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your build gradle file:

```
 dependencies {
     implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0'
}
```