# No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have been on this problem for a couple hours. After downloading a repository from github, the only error in any .xml file is:

```
No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'
```

The code is very straightforward, but there is not one straightforward answer I have found, on how to alleviate the error.

here is the code (in file res/values/styles.xml):

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

The project is located at: https://github.com/erikswed/InstaChatX
I am on Windows, using Eclipse Kepler

Comment: you need to reference AppCompat from the support library

Comment: what are the steps for taht? where is AppCompat located?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**What are the steps for that? where is AppCompat located?**

Download the support library here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

If you are using Eclipse:

Go to the tabs at the top and select ( Windows -> Android SDK Manager ). Under the 'extras' section, check 'Android Support Library' and check it for installation.

[image]

After that, the AppCompat library can be found at:

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

You need to reference this AppCompat library in your Android project.

Import the library into Eclipse.

1. Right click on your Android project.
2. Select properties.
3. Click 'add...' at the bottom to add a library.
4. Select the support library
5. Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I'm on windows, but that does not work...is there anything else that would work?

Comment: I hate to ask this, but could you provide more detailed steps?

Comment: @Eatlon what more do you need. It does not matter whether on window sor linux

Comment: @Eatlon the appcompact is always located @ `android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` under the android-sdk. You need to download that first. pls look at the docs. it does not work which step does not work. what details you need

Comment: @Eatlon i have used it many times. I am sure if you do it right it will work. Also it does not work. I see no code no snap shots nothing. How do you expect me to help further? And what project are you using.? No info

Comment: thank you, I have provided the location of the project I  am working on. (Minor detail is changing a few switch/case to if-then before working on it) Do you have an email address?

Comment: @Eatlon i do but it is not for personal assistance and post how you referenced AppCompat. The project required AppCOmpat

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I ended up following these instructions and it worked perfectly. Just like the 'using eclipse' tag:http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Comment: yes I will, but I'm relatively newer to Android and have been looking for someone to work with on this project. It's particularly interesting and has a new application to the market. Any interest in working on it?

Comment: Thank you Raghunandan.  I have been searching for this solution for a few days (in my spare time thank goodness)!

Comment: I didn't have "Android Support Library" in "Android SDK Manager".Here is information how I found it:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11533149/1970278

Comment: In the version of the SDK manager that I have (25.2.5), I do not see the Android Support Library there. I am getting this same error but cannot fix the problem with this recommended solution.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper Can you post a screen shot of your sdkmanager with Android-Studio

Answer (score 18):

If you are looking for the solution in **Android Studio** :

1. **Right click** on your app
2. **Open Module Settings**
3. Select **Dependencies** tab
4. Click on green **+** symbol which is on the right side
5. Select **Library Dependency**
6. Choose **appcompat-v7** from list

Comment: I have same problem, but it didn't work for me: Error:(4, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main16] D:\Android-Studio-Prj\Android\core\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'AppCompat.Light'.

Answer (score 3):

The steps described above do work, however I've encountered this problem on IntelliJ IDEA and have found that I'm having these problems with existing projects and the only solution is to remove the 'appcompat' module (not the library) and re-import it.

Comment: How do you remove the appcompat module? On which directory and file name please.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the steps you can try it out to resolve the issue: -

1. Provide reference of AppCompat Library into your project.
2. If option 1 doesn't solve the issue then you can try to change the style.xml file to below code.

```
 parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"
```

instead.

```
 parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

But option 2 will require minimum sdk version 14.

Hope this will help !

Summved

Comment: Intente muchas de las soluciones propuestas en otros foros y esta fue la unica que me funciono en Eclipse NEON, En los menus cambie "app" por xmlns:compat="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" ....  compat:showAsAction="never"/> además el mínimo de versión  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" /> en manifest. Además agregue la librería como referencia externa android-support-v7-appcompat.jar y funciono.

Comment: This will process javac without error. But then fatal program exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;`