# Error while importing android-support-v7-appcompat error: Error: No resource found

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have followed the eaxct method found at ./sdk/docs/tools/support-library/setup.html but when import v7-appcompat into workspace , it gives the error in the Android Manifest File

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/
 Theme.AppCompat').

Comment: the library is not refernced properly. check this http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok found a way do it. ..
I changed the v7-appcompat project's(in the workspace) **target sdk version to latest version**,
then i right clicked the project closed it , and then opened it again , and the error was gone , strange but it worked.....

Answer (score 0):

you need adding support v7 project as library project to your project or using Gradle to handle it .

Comment: actually I have not even added another project, I have just imported the v7compat. It was added to work space with the error,any help , thank you

Comment: do you want use v7compat in your project of modify it !?

Comment: actually i want to use v7 in my project, but its not even being imported properly, when i import the v7compat for the first time it have the theme error, i have used it in another project , the project have an red exclamation mark, its probably because of the error

Comment: see your libs folder on v7comp project do you see jar file named support v7?

Answer (score 0):

Even i have come across for the same problem in my project,
first update the SDK for available updates,once SDK is updated restart the eclipse,
thats it ,working fine for me now