# Errors after importing appcompact v7

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Even after making another workspace, after uploading the appcompact v7, i have a lot of errors like these:

```
 - error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

I need it to be fixed quickly, because i have to work with my projects, that now throw a red exclamation mark

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while importing android-support-v7-appcompat error: Error: No resource found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026670/error-while-importing-android-support-v7-appcompat-error-error-no-resource-fou)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml

Comment: so i have to download the latest android version and change target of appcompact v7 to the new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

Answer (score 0):

Appcompat

Check Build Target of your project and appcompat_v7 library project. They should be same, if your project has lesser Build Target than you get this error and won't be able to build.

To fix the problem in Eclipse go to Project->Properties->Android (Project Build Target) and select equal to your appcompat library project.

Comment: So I choosed in both appcompact and project api 19, and they still don't work. It's all because imported appcompact contains a whole bunch of errors like "No resource found that matches the given name".