# App crashes when changing theme to noTitle

Tags: android, android-theme

I've got a little app where I have a title bar present. I want to get rid of it and read that I should change the theme in the manifest to `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`. (It was `@style/AppTheme`

I had to browse the noTitle theme from the system resources and added it.

Now, if I boot up the app it says it 'unfortunately stopped working'.

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.esrmdesign"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.esrmdesign.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.esrmdesign.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

logcat:

```
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.esrmdesign/com.example.esrmdesign.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.example.esrmdesign.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-15 05:15:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your logcat error here

Comment: post your `MainActivity` code.

Comment: Your clearly said if you used `ActionBar Activity` then your must used theme `Theme.AppCompat`. It's because you an access `Actionbar` only with turn on (Visible) `Title Bar`.

Comment: Check this answer, I hope it will help.


 http://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/569713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

This exception is  thrown when you are using `appcompat` library for `ActionBar` and not setting a compatible theme in your manifest file. The compatible themes can be for e.g

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

If you are using `appcompat` library to support `ActionBar` from API 7 or more, you need to keep track of the following info,

1.Always use the latest `appcompat` library.

2.Don't forget to add compatible theme like below as per your need.
   e.g:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

3.Don't use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the Java file i.e don't hide the `TitleBar`. Because `ActionBar` is the replacement of it.

Comment: Do I still have the noTitle than?

Comment: Using `ActionBar` will automatically replace the titlebar of the Activity.

Comment: `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/ThemeAppCompat.Light')`

Comment: I guess there is some problem in your library set up. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21059804/1665507

Comment: It had appcompat v7, not it has v7 and v7_2. Applying the library shows same error again.

Comment: You missed a . after `Theme`

Comment: It worked out in the end :) I still have the actionbar to worry about now, though :-p Can't I hide that too?

Comment: @CaptainCarl: Open a new thread along with proper code.This answer is not appropriate to address this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use an `ActionBar` in your `Activity` which is the reason you are getting the `IllegalStateException`.

Change the theme to `android:theme="@style/ThemeAppCompat.Light"` as suggested in the `Exception` stacktrace