# Can't use the appcompat support library

Tags: android, xml, aide-ide

I want to use the appcompat for my project in AIDE.
so I downloaded the jar file, add it into lib folder & coded my project.
but when I theming, by putting the code

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

into AndroidManifest.xml, it gets an error, showing that no resources found that matches the name.
I modified the project.properties file, but still the same thing happens.
what shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppCompact is a Library project. You must reference it in your Andorid Project instead of adding it as a jar.

Read

[No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

Comment: it's worked. Thank you, But why is it work from the library project from existing source code instead of library jar?

Comment: @pawan_vimukthi read about library projects with resources. AppCompat is a Library project with resources

Comment: it means the jar file is the part of the library project.

Comment: @pawan_vimukthi why don't you read the docs. Its all there. May be it answers your questions http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html. If you still have doubts then come back and comment. Read topic Adding libraries with resources..