# Eclipse Error on styles value

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried to install Eclipse but I have this problem that I never see before. The problem is:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

I didn't do anything on the project. Basically I just create the project as android to work on it and I find this error. The error is in the res/values, res/values-v11, res/value-v14. The text is the same that you can find on normal Eclipse:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
```

The same block code is in the other two classes. All the < > are closed (because, as I said, I didn't change anything in the code). I read something in the site but nothing corresponds to my version of the application.

What do you thing about it? What should I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Install `Android Support Library,` go to Window -> Android Sdk Manager. Check Android Support Library and click install.

**update**: your problem is similar to this:

**[No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)**

Comment: Ok I did it. Now there is a problem with R. I import it but there is an error with setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); The error is: Multiple markers at this line
 - R cannot be resolved to a variable
 - activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a 
  field 
Even if R is imported

Comment: Damn..... I lose R. Is there a possibility to have it back? It looks like Eclipse deletes it

Comment: No errors, more than this I have an error in the Manifest where Eclipse hates the line of "android-theme"   
     
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@styles/app_name" >