# Android - Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library, android-appcompat

This issue has been covered before, but none of the solutions I looked at worked for me. I used apktool to decompile an `APK` I created a while back, but didn't have the code for. At first I was getting issues I found out were a result of not having a support library, so I set that up, then almost every single line of code in `attrs.xml`. A solution I found for that told me to just rename the name that had been assigned to it, so I did that, and the errors were gone. Now I'm getting these errors every time I try to run my project, despite no errors being highlighted in any of the files:

```
[2014-08-26 11:49:10 - CoolSketch] C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\styles_base.xml:261: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base.DropDownItem'.    
[2014-08-26 11:49:10 - CoolSketch] C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\styles_base.xml:323: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base'.    
[2014-08-26 11:49:10 - CoolSketch] C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\styles_base.xml:347: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base'.    
[2014-08-26 11:49:10 - CoolSketch] C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\themes_base.xml:189: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Base'.    
[2014-08-26 11:49:10 - CoolSketch] C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\apktool\CoolSketch\res\values-v14\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat'.
```

I believe I set the `appcompat` support library up wrong, although the only thing I changed was the build target, although I changed that back after errors arose, figuring it would be best to change it later if needed. Any ideas on what the issue/s is/are?

Comment: Just as a side note, thanks to those who helped format my original question.

Comment: What IDE do you use, Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: @Joseph I use Eclipse.

Comment: Do you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light?

Comment: @Joseph Neither of those fixed the problem.