# New Android project fails to create successfully

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I want to create an android project in eclipse. Seems simple enough. I downloaded and installed:

eclipse version:

```
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800
```

ADT version latest from:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

On windows 64 bit.

When I create a new project I follow the wizard with the following settings:

Application Name: DemoProject
Project Name: DemoProject
Package Name:com.example.demoproject
Min SDK: API8
Target: API21
Compile with API21
Theme: Holo light with dark action bar

Create customer launcher icon, create activity, create project in the workspace

Icon is text, ImF,full padding and circle option.

I then choose Blank Activity and leave defaults on the next page. I then press finish. The wizard page remains open and the following appear in the console view:

```
[2014-11-25 22:39:15 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:15 - DemoProject] 
[2014-11-25 22:39:15 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:15 - DemoProject] 
[2014-11-25 22:39:15 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:15 - DemoProject] 
[2014-11-25 22:39:16 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:16 - DemoProject] 
[2014-11-25 22:39:16 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:16 - DemoProject] 
[2014-11-25 22:39:16 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:16 - DemoProject] 
[2014-11-25 22:39:21 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:21 - DemoProject] 
[2014-11-25 22:39:21 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:21 - DemoProject] 
[2014-11-25 22:39:21 - DemoProject] C:\Users\Andy\workspace\DemoProject\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-11-25 22:39:21 - DemoProject]
```

Really not sure what the next step is!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Android SDK Manager and download Android Support Library like explained here: [No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light).

Since you want to support Api from level 8, and from that themes changes a lot, you need some libraries to do "retro compatibility"..
Also pay attention when you code, to manage different versions and to import correct package.

Comment: This was actually installed - but the source didnt exist in the directory it should have, so i deleted the package - re installed and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Add the app-compat-v7 library to your project. You can download it from your SDK Manager. Look for Support libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem like you and I found the way to fix it.
I'm sure that you didn't install Android Support Library in SDK Manager. (You can't see the Appcompat_v7 appear when you try to create a project.)

#### How to install that?

Open SDK Manager, check to the 'Obsolete' box, find the 'Android Support Library' package in 'Extras' group and install it.

After then, your project can be create normally.

[image: Android SDK Manager screenshot]