# requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) ERROR

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I'm having trouble putting my application fullscreen in Android Lollipop, my code :

```
public class AoA extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void oncreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);

        setupParameters();
    }

    public void setupParameters() {
        GameParameterSingleton.ORIENTATION = GameParameterSingleton.PORTRAIT;

        GameParameterSingleton.SCREEN_HEIGHT= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        GameParameterSingleton.SCREEN_WIDTH = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    } 
}
```

The application works when I do not use fullscreen, 
Can anyone help me as I leave fulllscreen ? as I take the title of the application?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: what is the error you getting

Comment: "Can anyone help me as I leave fullscreen", "as I take the title of the application" - please be more specific about these sentences, what exactly is the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: I can not get the titles bar

Comment: This error is only giving the API 21 in previous versions was working perfect

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in API 21

```
this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Doesn't work .

Try to Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Or add this

```
this.getActionBar().hide();
```

in `onCreate` method after         `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: changed the line of code in AndroidManifest.xml but did not work

Comment: @PabloReis Do you want to display your activity without title bar and without actionbar ?

Comment: In my AndroidManifest.xml

Code contains the line:

android : theme = "@ styleAppTheme ">

Every time I change it displays error

Comment: I put the ActionBar the line of code, but also presented an error,
ActionBar displays error

- Call reuires API Level 11 (Current mini is 8)

Comment: My answer works.Maybe there is something wrong with your project.What is your error ?

Comment: I 'm developing a basic game in android I left my comment as ContextView ( R.layout.activity_game ) ;

and added setContextView ( GameScreen ) ;

my class where I work with the game screen , the application works perfect but when put to take the titles he 's procedural error bar in the emulator and there for all

Comment: you should call `setContextView()` before `getActionbar.hide()`.what is your error while adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to your manifest 
?

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml error is

error : Error : No resource found That matches the give name (at 'Theme ' with value ' @ styleTheme.No.TitleBar.Fullscreen ') .

Comment: what about `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`

Comment: What version android you advise me develop so that there is this error? I'm thinking of porting my system to the previous version , to try to end this error.

what do you think ?.

Comment: are you sure that support library is installed ? see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light

Comment: I have installed all sdk libraries to the last launched

Comment: what is your target sdk

Comment: 19 a 21 is my target sdk

Comment: use this <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: and compile ? is 21 ?