# Android Error retrieving parent

Tags: java, android

I got this error... I don't know how to fix it... Could somebody please help me?

I got this on 3 files, but all 3 the same error...

error:

> Error:(7, -1) Android Resource Packaging: [rpr-app]
>   C:\Users***\Documents***\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

One file:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **support libraries** from *SDK Manager* if you don't have installed.

And then if you are using ***Android Studio*** then,

From Android Studio, different than Eclipse:

**1.** Open the `build.gradle` file of your project.

**2.** Include the `appcompat` to it.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

Or if you are using ***Eclipse*** then,

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

**Edit:**

Open `build.gradle(Module: app)` from the files tree on the left side of the IDE.

[image]

Then add this to that file and sync it again

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the "build.gradle" because I don't have one.

Comment: I'm using andoid studio, I can't find that 'tree'.. :$

Comment: Open your android studio first and there will be a list of files on the left side from that list you will see build.gradle under Gradle Scripts.

Comment: Do you see the files list on the left side?? (I am seeing) find build.gradle and open it and make changes I have suggested in answer and also install support library if you don't already have installed

Comment: I don't see the build.gradle, Is it possible i don't have it?

Comment: If it is impossible, how is it possible that I can't find it?

Comment: Man if you have learned android from beginning, you can easily find it out. [See the highlighted part in this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/uTdzyCv.png) it is called tree of files where all files of your project are listed. And there must will be `gradle.build(Module: app)` find it, open it, and under `dependencies{...}` copy `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be targeting a very low API level.

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, change the android:minSdkVersion to like 15. You'll still target a majority of android devices and won't have to deal with compatibility issues.