# first android application on eclipse make some problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I am trying to create an hello world android application on Eclipse.
After I install the adk, sdk, jde, ide and etc its time to work.
When I try to create android application, its show me that errors:

```
[2015-09-29 17:29:23 - Helloworld] E:\Users\user\workspace\Helloworld\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-09-29 17:29:23 - Helloworld] 
[2015-09-29 17:29:23 - Helloworld] E:\Users\user\workspace\Helloworld\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-09-29 17:29:23 - Helloworld] 
[2015-09-29 17:29:23 - Helloworld] E:\Users\user\workspace\Helloworld\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-09-29 17:29:23 - Helloworld]
```

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light

Comment: From someone who made the transition from the Eclipse Android SDK to Android Studio: use Android Studio, even if you are a hardcore eclipse user. I can't even begin to list all the benefits of Android Studio, but the most important one is probably simply that it's the new standard.

Comment: Exactly. The only reason why I see anyone using Eclipse is if they don't have around 6-8 gigs of ram.

Comment: i used the android studio, but i came with a problem..
its minimize the images and when i try to make them bigger its get blurry...

Comment: maybe you guys can help me with this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850147/blur-image-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to download the support library
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

You have the error AppCompat not found because your support library isn't present.

Comment: Did you reference them in Eclipse? Right click on your project and add the support library. Your project must know where the library is.

Comment: i have clicked right click on my project => android tools => add support liabry.. 
its install couple of thing but i also restart the eclipse and its still dont work..