# blur image in android studio

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, imageview

I"m trying to make background image in black activity..
this is the image i try to upload..
[image]
i add a photo in res -> new -> image asset and i locate the image and select it..
after i add "imageview" to my activity and choose the resourse that i have created...

this is how it go:
[image]

Comment: How is this question related to the term `blur`?

Comment: I didn't find the question, though.

Comment: lol, i was trying to add image to my activity and some how its get blur as you can see in the second image..

Comment: You possibly dropped the image into the wrong drawable folder. So, at different densities, it will be scaled

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution..

transfer the image to the folder drawable..

then click on background -> project ___ get down down until you found it and TA DAM!!!

- do not name the file with special chars like - or _ .

thx guys!!