# Error retrieving parent from item

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

This may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light).

But it seems like those solutions didn't solve this error for me.

This is my error[image]

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">#F5F5F5</item>
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Yes I've got the references to the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` dll's.

Really weird because when my project is in `Debug mode` it runs without giving me any error. This error only occurs when it's in `Release mode` and I try to create an APK file for mobile testing.[image]

Comment: Make sure you rebuild you project for release.  The release code may be using an older version of your source code.  To make sure project completely rebuilds delete the bin folder in project which will force the entire code to rebuild. Backup bin folder before deleting just incase you improperly have source code in folder.

Comment: please do NOT post error messages as images.  Google cannot index an image.  Take the time to paste and format the text of the error message appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Build your app, with latest platform Android 6.O