# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable

Tags: android

I am new with ActionBarActivity, my application get crashed while running following code in eclipse
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Where I already import

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

but still I got an errors in LogCat as follows:

```
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320): Process: com.element45.android.localsale.activities, PID: 320
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.element45.android.localsale.activities.Login.onCreate(Login.java:18)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.element45.android.localsale.activities-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  ... 17 more
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):      ... 18 more
01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should use **#Android Studio instead of Eclipse** .

> 01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.element45.android.localsale.activities-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] 01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   01-27 16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 01-27
>   16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) 01-27
>   16:47:13.091: E/AndroidRuntime(320):  ... 17 more 01-27 16:47:13.091:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(320):  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

**NoClassDefFoundError** error is thrown when the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) or an instance of the ClassLoader class tries to load the definition of a class, but the definition could not be found.

**Bad Approach** : ***Using Deprecated Code (ActionBarActivity).***

At first extends **AppCompatActivity instead of ActionBarActivity** .

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
  // ...
}
```

**Advice**

set `android:minSdkVersion` version .

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

Try this way ,Hope it woks .

Answer (score 0):

1. Install android support package in Android SDK Manager
   [Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwH99.png)
2. Add AppCompatActivity package to your gradle config

   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
3. Check min SDK version

Comment: user using `eclipse `

Comment: Problem is not within the IDE

Comment: min sdk version is 17 and also have android-support-v7-appcompact.jar file still have same error

Comment: Look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)
and also try to use AppCompatActivity