# Android SDK does not show the Android support library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-sdk-2.3

I am new to Android development. I just installed Android SDK and with required packages.

In eclipse, I created my first Android project and came through all the steps of the wizard until the final step. In the last step, when I finish the creation of the project, the wizard does not disappear, but the project gets created with some errors(which are some popular errors among developers).

the error is :

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

I came through a suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light) and the suggestion is to install 
the `Android Support Library.`

But in my SDK manager, it does not show the package for `Android Support Library.` under Extras. Why is that? How can I install the `Android Support Library.` using my SDK manager.

A screen shot of my SDK manager is given below. You can see that Android Support Library is not there even though support repository is there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution finally.

- RMB on the project
- Android tools -> Add support library
- It will install the Android support library(In my case it installed an obsolete version. I do not know why)
- Then, in the SDK manager, Android Support Library can be seen after adding a tick to show the obsolete packages.
- But cannot update it. Don't know why
- Clean and build the project
- Follow steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

Comment: I am still looking for an answer as to why the support library is obsolete. Is there a way I can use the repository option instead or is that totally a Maven/Gradle thing?

Comment: I came across the same problem with you. When I click "add support library", an error  "Android Support Jar not found:]C:\Users\allen\Desktop\v4\android-support-v4.jar" occurs. Besides, I still cannot see "Android Support Library" in the SDK manager. Do you have any ideas?