# Error when setup android by eclipse and ADT

Tags: android

When I try to create a virtual machine, I get an error like this:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check what is causing the red underline. Be more specific

Comment: With all due respect, probably, you'll be better off working on 'Android Studio'.
Its the official IDE for Android development, by Google itself.
Atleast, I've been informed to be so !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Android Support Library` to your project

1. Download Android Support Library by Android SDK Manager (it's in `extras`)
2. Import and add it to your project (it is in `SDK/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` directory)
3. Clean and rebuild project

Also please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

Comment: Hi. In my extras I just have the support repository and I already installed that.

Comment: Did you import it to the project ?

Comment: Well I still dont know how to import it. Right-click and choose import as well but didnt find the location.