# Android Support Library in Xamarin Build

Tags: android, xamarin, build, tfsbuild, android-build

I set up a Xamarin Build :

[image]

I have these errors :

[image]

I understand what he's telling me, Widget.Design.TabLayout comes from Android Support Library.
I need to add Android Support Library in my Xamarin Build.
For a classic xamarin project, It works this way : 
[No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

But on a build setting, I trully don't know !
Do you have ideas ?

Comment: Are you using on-premise TFS or VSTS? Are you using on-premises build agent or hosted pool?

Comment: I use VSTS with xbuild. hosted pool.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Support Package is not automatically added to a Xamarin.Android application. Xamarin provides the [Android Support Library v4 component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv4-18) to simplify adding the support libraries to a Xamarin.Android application.

You can follow the article below to add components in your project:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/components_walkthrough/

Comment: Thx, I knew it, but how can I do it with xbuild ! On the TFS xbuild (xamarin build on TFS)

Comment: After adding the component to your project, check in your project to TFS, then try to build your project.