# I'm using Eclipse and Android and a lot of things are messed up in the MainActivity XML

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I don't know why there are so many errors. I think I am missing the app theme but I don't know how to add it if you would show me that would be great, thank you. I thought I installed all the necessary items.

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Log

```
[2016-08-09 20:13:03 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:03 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-08-09 20:13:03 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:03 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-08-09 20:13:03 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:03 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-08-09 20:13:04 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:04 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-08-09 20:13:04 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:04 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-08-09 20:13:04 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:04 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-08-09 20:13:26 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:26 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-08-09 20:13:26 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:26 - HelloWorld] 
[2016-08-09 20:13:26 - HelloWorld] H:\Eclipse workspace\HelloWorld\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-08-09 20:13:26 - HelloWorld]
```

Comment: first you are missing this theme Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Comment: Those errors are related to xmls in your res folder and have nothing to do with the Java code. Try updating your question with the contents of your styles xmls.

Comment: As per [google annoncement](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)  Google Ends Support for Android Eclipse Tools.you have to start your new project on studio

Comment: @krishnan While I agree with you that Android Studio should be used, we aren't Google, so we support anyone with reasonable questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

Answer (score 0):

`AppCompat` is a library project. You need to reference the library project in your android project.

Check this for information on adding library with resources - https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library.

Though, I also agree with krishnan's comment - switch to Android Studio and save yourself some trouble :)

Hope this helps!