# No Resource Found That Matches The Given Name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light' with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, styles

I am configuring eclipse for android development. After downloading all the necessary files from SDK, i tried creating a project in eclipse but it failed. It shows me an error as shown in the image below:
[image]

I found a solution here at stackoverflow that suggests to import the library from the project properties but unfortunately that didn't work because i don't find anything to import; here's the screenshot:
[image]

Here's the `styles.xml` file for my project:
[image]

PS: I have already installed **Android Support Repository** through SDK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

Comment: Check this link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library

Comment: first of all switch to Android Studio. It runs faster, uses dependencies and will solve all your problems..