# gradle build error in Androidmanifest.xml file

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build an android application using gradle in eclipse and i am trying to build the apk using command **gradle build** in project root directory,
i am getting an error in the path of

> $projdir/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/Androidmanifest.xml

saying that

> /build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml:139:28-68:     AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar').

When i open eclipse and it is redirecting me to the resource fine and it is showing no errors. And i think the `Androidmanifest.xml` in the above path is it necessary ??

Comment: Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version. Check the version first.

Comment: my compileSdkVersion and  buildToolsVersion '25.0.2' in build.gradle How to get support library's major version??

Comment: Is the compileSdkVersion  and buildToolsVersion  in build.gradle must be same??

Comment: Did you try to add the AppCompat dependency? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light

Answer (score 1):

```
Use AppTheme like this :-   

 <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
```